# using share kit to share the image on Facebook

Tags: ios, xcode, sharekit

Just like the title , I just followed the step by this website :

http://labs.grupow.com/blog/2012/03/05/sharekit-2-dot-0

and there was no any error to run the app , but about the result of pressing share button which was showing the action sheet ,there is some problem .

After I press the "Facebook" , and go to the authorize page , during the 1st time , at the top right corner , there was a "log in" button . When the 2nd time , it appear "okay" only . I know that this is normal and no anything is being wrong . But , the main problem was that , I can't share my image on the Facebook wall . And also text . I want to know the method to solve this .

(I am not good at english..)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most probably you do not have properly configured Facebook's single sign on (SSO) callback.

Implement step 7 from sharekit's [install wiki](https://github.com/ShareKit/ShareKit/wiki/Installing-sharekit).

Comment: Thanks for your reply . I have done the step 7 before , it will turn back to the app after pressing "Ok" . However , there was no anything had posted on the wall .

Comment: ShareKit does not remember your credentials (token). Step through this routine in your app delegate: - (BOOL)handleOpenURL:(NSURL*)url
{
NSString* scheme = [url scheme];
  if ([scheme hasPrefix:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"fb%@", SHKCONFIG(facebookAppId)]])
    return [SHKFacebook handleOpenURL:url];
  return YES;
} and make sure, that [SHKFacebook ...] is called